# Store different (unmodifiable) types in a List

Tags: c#, object, casting, base-class, downcast

I am using two different libraries each having their own type for a point. Both types have x and y coordinates while each has also some special fields. I would like to store both types (say `PointA` and `PointB`) in a List. I can't use base-class since `PointA` and `PointB` are library types and cannot be modified.

There is this thing that I have to actually use a List inside a List (an array of array of points). The method I call from *Library1* returns `List<PointA>` and the library2's method returns `List<PointB>`.

What is the best way to store these arrays of points inside one List? Using `List<List<Object>>` and casting each object from the returned array to Object? Seems like this could be done more elegantly.

Comment: Do `PointA` and `PointB` share a common `interface` or base-type (other than `object`)?

Comment: Have you considered using an adaptor pattern? Each adaptor could store one of the types of points, and you would store a list of point adaptors.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Even if they have member values in common they can't be used interchangeable in any way (unless those libraries are built to do that in some way, e.g. using reflection or a common interface).

Comment: @Marc, no, they don't share a common interface; the types are from two different libraries. @ Jonny: I don't wuite understand what you mean yet but I'm going to look into it meanwhile.

Comment: Can you make both types (PointA and PointB) to realize an interface, say, IPoint? In that case it'll be possible to write List<IPoint>

Comment: @Mario: I just need a container to store the objects. When using them later I'll cast them to the proper type.

Comment: How do you know the proper type? If you've stored a `PointA`, you won't be able to cast it to `PointB`.

Comment: Only one type of objects will be in the `List` at a time. I just don't know which.

Comment: Ah, ok. This case my example should work pretty well, although not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only think of one possible solution. Create your own "wrapper" class handling the type unification/conversion (untested):

```
class StoredPoint {
    PointA pa;
    PointB pb;

    public StoredPoint (PointA other) {
        pa = other;
        // pb is null
    }

    public StoredPoint (PointB other) {
        pb = other;
        // pa is null
    }

    public static implicit operator StoredPoint(PointA other) {
        return new StoredPoint(other);
    }

    public static implicit operator StoredPoint(PointB other) {
        return new StoredPoint(other);
    }

    public static implicit operator PointA(StoredPoint point) {
        if (pa != null)
            return pa;
        return PointA(0,0); // some default value in case you can't return null
    }

    public static implicit operator PointA(StoredPoint point) {
        if (pa != null)
            return pa;
        return PointA(0,0); // some default value in case you can't return null
    }

    public static implicit operator PointB(StoredPoint point) {
        if (pb != null)
            return pb;
        return PointB(0,0); // some default value in case you can't return null
    }
  }
```

Then you could just create a list using `List<StoredPoint>` and add both types of points to it. Whether you're able to use the resulting list is some different issue (mostly due to error handling etc.).

Comment: Just as a note. In case you won't mix types, you could just use a `List<object>` and in addition store whether you've got `PointA` or `PointB` inside and cast the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the non-generic `ArrayList`, as found in the `System.Collections` library.

But a better option would probably be that you create your own point class and convert the `PointA` and `PointB` objects to it.

For instance, say you define your own type PointList:

```
public class PointList : List<MegaPoint>
```

(where `MegaPoint` is your own definition of a point).

So every item in the list is guaranteed to be of type `MegaPoint`. Then, if you want to add lists of the other types, implement methods such as:

```
public void AddFrom(List<PointA> points)
```

and

```
public void AddFrom(List<PointB> points)
```

which don't just add the items, but convert them to your "generic" `MegaPoint`s.

Now your code can use the libraries as needed but your List will always contain a single type, `MegaPoint`, that contains the right properties for your application.